# How can I generate this type pdf file by itextsharp?

Tags: select, fonts, itext

I get a pdf  generate by itextsharp. In this pdf,all text cannot be selected, and when display, we don't need other fonts.  How can I generate this type pdf file? thks！

this file link: [demo file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i50zUCH)

Comment: Your PDF does not contain any text except the "39 - 39" at the bottom. This explains why text (other than the "39 - 39") cannot be selected and no special fonts are needed. What it contains instead are loads of vector graphics which paint what looks like text. Thus, all you have to do is use the `PdfContentByte` methods for painting vector graphics, for drawing and filling paths, and paint your desired PDF content with them.

Comment: Thks your reply! I try following code,but in the pdf ,the "sample text" still can be selected.  How I improve my code,thk.   @mkl

Comment: In your example you still use text operations. Text operations require fonts. The sample document does not use text operations. It uses operations like **moveTo**, **lineTo**, **curveTo**, and **fill** to paint text. To create something like that sample,  use such operations to paint content.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea we can make text of a page to vector graphics, then put into pdf file?? Or have other solution,the result pdf canot be modified and can print very clear. thks. @mkl

Comment: most likely the software that created the example PDF did use the glyph drawing instructions from some font to paint the text. You can similarly use a library for font handling to read the glyph drawing instructions (which mostly are vector graphic drawing instructions) from the font and paint the text using these instructions I  iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

I try following code,but in the pdf ,the "sample text" still can be selected. How I improve my code,thk.

string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString();

```
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();//  
    Document doc = new Document((PageSize.A5.Rotate()));//  
    PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outputStream);
    doc.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    cb.BeginText();
    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false), 10f);
    cb.SetTextMatrix(1.2f, 9.5f);
    cb.ShowText("Sample text");
    cb.EndText();
    doc.Close();

    outputStream.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.OutputStream.Write(outputStream.GetBuffer(), 0, outputStream.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.OutputStream.Close();
```